# Is it possible to control an active application using an Android phone?

Tags: raspbian, android

I have an application written in c, on Raspberry Pi, which starts in a sort of "waiting mode" and uses two buttons connected to the GPIO as "start" and "stop". 
I was thinking about controlling it with an Android phone, and I found out the PiUi project. 
Would it be possible to send commands to an active applications using PiUi?
Or there is a better solution?

Thanks to everyone that will help.

Comment: What about a webpage?

Comment: A webpage would require that the Raspberry is connected to the Internet, wouldn't it? I prefer to be able to control it even without Internet

Comment: It could be running on the Pi and only serve local clients on the same network

Answer (score 1):

The PiUi interface is written and controlled in Python.  This could be used to control your C program, but such interactivity won't happen magically. You will need to build some kind of listening interface into your C application. That could be done using message queues, shared memory, pipes, ports, or a number of other things.

It looks like PiUi is simply a framework for creating a local webpage.  It may be simpler to just create one yourself as @SteveRobillard has suggested in the comments.